# What are the time out changes should make to client application that use WCF service?

Tags: wcf

My wcf service excutes many SQL queries.After I will send an XML file to client application.

It takes more tha 30 mins to execute all the queries.

WCF Service is executing successfully on DataBase.

But client application is crashing before getting response from my service. It is crashing for around 20 mins.

I made the following time out changes in client config file. But still client application is crashing.

closeTimeout="04:20:00" openTimeout="04:20:00" receiveTimeout="04:00:00" sendTimeout="04:00:00"

Any idea?

Thanks,
JN

Comment: Set the timeouts to similar values on your service as well - most likely the service is timing out on the sendTimeout after the default setting (1 minute, I believe).  Although, if you're running a query that takes 30 minutes via a WCF call, you might want to a) try and optimize your query or b) take a different approach to the problem - 30 minutes for a client to wait for a response seems like an awfully long time.

Answer (score 2):

Do not wait that long for a service to return. I would go the async way and fire a message to start the XML generation process. Then either go back to the service once in a while to check the status of the assignment, or have a duplex binding and let the service call back to the client to indicate progress or that the job has completed.

Workflow Foundation might offer you some good opportunities to make this complex asynchronous behavior more simple. Take one of the samples in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741723(v=vs.90).aspx to get yourself up to speed.